# Ajax Control for tabs or Javascript? (An aspx page with tabbed content)

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax

I have an ASP.NET website (c# as code behind) in which one of my pages has tabbed content. I have done it in two different ways, and now I am deciding which one is the way to go. One way, I have done it with javascript. Simply making swapping divs depending on which one is clicked,  and this is working great (other than some minor flickering issues...). The other way, I have used the [Ajax Control Toolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/) and the Tabs control. I was looking up the benefits of Ajax, but also saw these downsides of using a tabbed interface with Ajax...

- Search engines don't see the data that isn't in the first tab, because they can't access the Ajax.
- The tabs cannot be bookmarked. So customers can't save the information they want.
- Ajax is not accessible, so the content in the other tabs would not be visible to anyone using a screen reader, or even older browsers that don't have good JavaScript support.
- If one of the tabs had a lot of information, it could take a long time to load on a slow connection. And because Ajax doesn't indicate anything is happening it looks like the page is broken.

Are all of these correct? I'm not so concerned about information not being found via search engine because only users of the site can see the content anyways.

So the main question is, what pros and cons to each method of implementation? Ajax definitely looks cleaner, but how does performance stack up?

Comment: Ajax or JavaScript? That's not a very useful title, since Ajax is a API for JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In answer to your points above:

> Search engines don't see the data that isn't in the first tab, because they can't access the Ajax.

Search engines index what they find on the page. If the data isn't there, they won't load it. However, if the URL that is used to retrieve the AJAX result is linked to as a separate page via a normal `<a>` tag, it is possible to index this.

> The tabs cannot be bookmarked. So customers can't save the information they want.

This is true, even if you use the non-AJAX solution.  To bookmark a tab, you have to effectively bookmark the page in a certain 'state'.  Using [hash fragments](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-bbq/examples/fragment-basic/) is a good way to achieve this.

> Ajax is not accessible, so the content in the other tabs would not be visible to anyone using a screen reader, or even older browsers that don't have good JavaScript support.

As with any content loaded via a script, if the user has scripts disabled, they don't get the content. As for browser support, jQuery and many other libraries abstract the browser differences away to support anything you could reasonably wish to support.

> If one of the tabs had a lot of information, it could take a long time to load on a slow connection. And because Ajax doesn't indicate anything is happening it looks like the page is broken.

Incorrect. The more data to load, the longer it will take to complete the HTTP request, yes. But "AJAX doesn't indicate anything is happening" is not true - it doesn't even make sense.  AJAX is a transport mechanism. The responsibility for showing the user that "something is happening" is up to you, and can be easily achieved with [spinning placeholders](http://ajaxload.info/) or suchlike.

Basically, AJAX keeps your initial page-load time to a minimum by only requesting the data needed for the initial UI state. Subsequent requests, as with any HTTP request (including page load), will take time, but the user experience gains are, in my opinion, vastly superior.

Comment: Actually, using AJAX would benefit you when you had a tab with a lot of content/slow connections; people who weren't interested in the content wouldn't have to wait for that content to load.

Comment: @parKing Agreed. Streamlining the initial page load is always worthwhile, especially with more mobile devices on 2/3/4G connections.

Answer (score 2):

> Search engines don't see the data that isn't in the first tab, because
>   they can't access the Ajax.

This is poorly worded. The data resides on the server so yes its inaccessible to the client until the ajax request completes and the DOM is populated. How important is the data in your first tab? If its that important than put it on the page layout.

> The tabs cannot be bookmarked. So customers can't save the information
>   they want.

Not sure what bookmarking has to do with saving customer information. Seems like two different things. But...

You can implement auto-save like gmail does. Use setTimeout to issue an ajax post back to the server to save a draft or bookmark preferences. Use hashtags to navigate page structure in a single-page application.

> Ajax is not accessible, so the content in the other tabs would not be
>   visible to anyone using a screen reader, or even older browsers that
>   don't have good JavaScript support.

Again, do you want people to screen scrape your site? jQuery does a fine job of supporting older browsers with $.ajax(). I was supporting IE6 and IE7 with jQuery Mobile and we made extensive use of $.ajax().

> If one of the tabs had a lot of information, it could take a long time
>   to load on a slow connection. And because Ajax doesn't indicate
>   anything is happening it looks like the page is broken.

You can use loading bars for this...

```
$.ajaxStart(function() { /* show spinner gif */ } );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an ajax feel where when you click a tab the page doesn't flicker, I would use jQuery.ajax.  You will have more control and there is plenty of support out there.

To handle the search engine issue you can provide a site map with url's representing each tab.

Good luck,
Tom

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/